# adding facebook like option in android application

Tags: android

I need add facebook like and twitter like option in my android application.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve it .whether i need to configure fb sdk and twitter sdk or i can be done with simply firing a intent with package name.

I don't need facebook like or twitter like button in my application
I have a dialog popup like this and on selection i have to do this.

```
 private void showSettingPopUp() {  
    String[] items={"Share","Facebook Like","Twitter Like","Review"};
    settingPopUp=new Dialog(BusinessesList.this,R.style.ThemeWithCorners);
    settingPopUp.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    settingPopUp.setContentView(R.layout.category_dialog_layout);
    ListView settingList=(ListView)settingPopUp.findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);
    settingList.setAdapter(new CustomDialogAdapter(BusinessesList.this,items));
    settingList.setOnItemClickListener(new SettingSelectorListner());
    settingPopUp.show();

}
```

SettingSelectorListner class

```
class SettingSelectorListner implements OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        settingPopUp.dismiss();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            shareText("share text");
            break;
        case 1:
            //fb like
            Intent fbIntent=new Intent();
            fbIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            fbIntent.setPackage("com.facebook");
            startActivity(fbIntent);
            break;
        case 2:

            //twitter like
            break;
        case 3:

            break;


        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
But for Facebook like you need to submit your app for facebook review.

```
private LikeView likeView  = null;

CallbackManager callbackManager;

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(OrderSummaryActivity.this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
                likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);  
                //              likeView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_facebook);
                likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
                /*likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                        "http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en",
                        LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);*/
                likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                        "PAGE_ID",
                        LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);



            }
        }, 2000);
```

XML Code:

```
 <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
                android:id="@+id/likeView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```